# How to shade region between polar curves in Grapher?

Tags: grapher

I've graphed two polar curves and would like to shade the region inside one and outside the other. When I select the two equations and then select `Integrate` from the Equation menu, I get the error message

> Cannot integrate the difference between the selected graphs.

It seems simple. Why can't Grapher do it?

In case it makes a difference, the two equations are `r = 6` (a circle) and `r = 6 - 6 sin(theta)` (a cardioid). I want to shade the region inside the cardioid but outside the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Grapher *can* do it. Using the conjunction `r > 6 & r < 6 - 6 sin (theta)`, we get the following

[image]